# populate dropdown value in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, internet-explorer, v-model

I'm trying to prepopulate dropdown value from API response in IE Browser. I'm able to populate in  chrome. Below is my code.

```
     <div>
        <p>State</p>
        <select id="stateType" v-model="countryState">
          <option  v-for="(statelist, index) in states" :key="index">{{ statelist.value }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

if(this.countryState!=null){
       for(var stateIndex=0; stateIndex<=this.states.length;stateIndex++){
          if(this.states[stateIndex].value==this.countryState)
            break;
        }
        document.getElementById("stateType").selectedIndex=stateIndex;
      }
```

Comment: What version of vue? Any errors in console?

Comment: its vue 2. Not printing any errors. But the dropdown is empty in UI

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in IE 11 with your code. I made a sample like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/skzruxve/1/) and it works well in IE 11. Which version of IE are you using? Please provide a code snippet which can **reproduce the issue**. You can use some online code editors to show your code to make it more clear.